# Java считает строку массивом

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Во всём коде где используется **s** который является строкой выводит ошибку

> Array type expected; found: 'java.lang.String'

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Enter string ");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        Integer n = s.length();
        for (int i = 1; i > n; i++){
            if ((s[i]='a')&&(s[i+1]='b')&&(s[i+2]='c')&&(s[i+3]='d')){
                for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
                        s[m] = s[m+1];
                    }
                    n = n-4;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }
```

Я пытаюсь сделать вот это задание: Даны натуральное число n, символы S1,.....,Sn. Удалить из данной последовательности все группы букв вида abcd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать метод `String.toCharArray()` чтобы получить массив `char` из строки. Дальше итерировать по этому объекту и соединить его в новую строку. Но в данном случае я думаю лучше воспользоваться готовыми решениями вроде:

```
String str = "Hello abcd world abcd";
str = str.replace("abcd", "");
System.out.print(str); // "Hello  world " - пробелы сохранены
```

Либо написать регулярное выражение

В любом случае, такие решения лучше:
1. Они не создают оверхеда, т.к. нет циклов в т.ч. вложенных.
2. Они будут работать безотказно, в то время как в самопальном цикле можно закосячить и поломать что-нибудь.
3. Они лучше для чтения и понимания, нежели разбираться в странных циклах и слипшихся условиях :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете обратиться к конкретному символу в строке, используя `s[i]`, так можно делать только с массивами. Чтобы получить символ нужен метод `charAt`, а для замены `replace` (однако он вернет новую строку ведь класс `String` неизменяемый, для изменения строки используйте `stringBuilder` или массив символов).

Comment: Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, пометьте мой ответ как правильный( мне будет приятно), если нет, задавайте вопросы в комментарии ниже

Comment: 1) Не стоит излишне торопить автора и выпрашивать плюшку. 2) Уведомлять стоит либо через `@Nick`, либо под его вопросом.

Comment: Просто мне нужно)))И спасибо